# Edit existing script to open in new tab on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created the following file which I am i-framing into the search boxes on my website. https://web.vtchamber.com/site-search/custom-search.aspx

Here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    window.siqConfig = {
        engineKey: "a11072522490d649e5d96a6c59df6ea3",
        forceLoadSettings: false        // change false to true if search box on your site is adding dynamically
    };
    window.siqConfig.baseUrl = "//pub.searchiq.co/";
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = window.siqConfig.baseUrl + '/js/container/siq-container-2.js?cb=' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*999999)) + '&engineKey=' + siqConfig.engineKey;
    script.id = "siq-container";
    document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

Here is the form html:

```
<form target="_blank" id="siq_searchForm">;
  <input type="search" placeholder="Type here to search..." value="" name="s" />
</form>
```

Although I have added the **target="_blank"** code to the form html, it will not open in a separate tab.  Can someone please help me edit the above script so that the  results page opens in a separate tab?

FYI I have researched similar questions/answers on this for hours and edited/tested code but cannot get the RESULTS to open in a new tab.

Comment: @connexo `target="_blank"` works for forms too: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/t41zpfh0/

Comment: Thanks for responding - I am aware of that but unable to effectively integrate the code into the script.  Can you suggest what to add?

Comment: `target` is a valid attribute for forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: There is no form submission that I can see in the code you have provided. Perhaps the siq-container-2.js has some submission or ajaxing?

Comment: Have you inspected the browser console to see what is happening? IS it that it is not opening in a different tab? or that it isn't opening at all?

Comment: @vtchamber I see that you have a file **autocomplete.js** which handles form submission, debug that code.. 

`siq_S(this).parents("form.siq_searchForm").submit()` in `bindFunctions`

Comment: A form with `target="_blank"` does indeed open the response in a new tab. If it does not, the reason must be within the iframe setup or in the JavaScript…

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary Unfortunately the autocomplete.js file is on SearchIQ.co's server - I do not have access to it.  I need to create a workaround in the script that I provided.

Comment: @mplungjan Unfortunately the siq-container-2.js  file is on SearchIQ.co's server - I do not have access to it. I need to create a workaround in the script that I provided.

Comment: That is not possible without replacing the obfuscated script with your own. I assume you still want the siq to process the form but just return the result in a new window?

Comment: Put breakpoints, debug through some of the resources that you say are on serve, I could see an error `https://api.searchiq.co/api/search/results?q=jlk&engineKey=a11072522490d649e5d96a6c59df6ea3&page=0&itemsPerPage=5&group=1&autocomplete=1 401 (Unauthorized)` just before the new frame loads after submission, probably this case needs to be handled, and you have to debug those resource files.